# Editing songs in iTunes 11.0.2

Tags: itunes, windows, music

I've recently got a new Windows laptop and downloaded and installed the latest iTunes (11.0.2). All my music (over 5000 songs) went into iTunes fine, just as they were on my old laptop. However I have now noticed that when I download new music and add it to my iTunes it won't allow me to edit the songs through "Get Info" even though the songs I transferred from my old laptop can be edited perfectly fine. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. check if you have relocated songs.
2. check if your files can be rewritten.

I use self-written python program to remove stale content.

```
import win32com.client
itunes= win32com.client.Dispatch("iTunes.Application")
ITTrackKindFile=1
mainLibrary = itunes.LibraryPlaylist
tracks = mainLibrary.Tracks
numTracks = tracks.Count
deletedTracks=0
batch_size = 90 
deleted = []
while True:
  while numTracks  !=0:
   currTrack=tracks.Item(numTracks)
   if currTrack.Kind == ITTrackKindFile:
       if currTrack.Location == "":
         deleted.append(currTrack)
   numTracks-=1
   for track in deleted:
      track.Delete()
      deletedTracks+=1
   del deleted[:] # free memory and close handles
   if not numTracks:
     break

if deletedTracks > 0:
if deletedTracks == 1:
  print "Removed 1 dead track."
else:
  print "Removed " + str(deletedTracks) + " dead tracks."
else:
  print "No dead tracks were found."
```

Comment: I've not relocated the songs because the songs play fine but I do use an external hard-drive so I don't know if that has anything to do with it? How do I check if files can be rewritten? Thanks for your help.

Comment: to check if files are relocated in any way, you should checkout info for path. To check existence you should type full path in Explorer's address field.

Comment: I guess that drive or path to your music folder has been changed since you moved to new laptop.

Comment: I've just added program which I use to remove stale tracks from library